# Using mutate on many columns at once, without writing them out explicitly

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame like this

```
d <- data.frame(id = 1:5, var1 = rep(1, 5), var2 = rep(2, 5),
    var3 = rep(3, 5), m = seq(0, 1, length.out = 5))
d
#  id var1 var2 var3    m
#   1    1    2    3 0.00
#   2    1    2    3 0.25
#   3    1    2    3 0.50
#   4    1    2    3 0.75
#   5    1    2    3 1.00
```

What I want to achieve is the outcome of

```
d[c("var1", "var2", "var3")] <- d[c("var1", "var2", "var3")] * d$m
```

but using `mutate()` instead, in one call (i.e. without writing `d %>% mutate(var1 = var1 * m) %>% mutate(var2 = var2 * m)` etc). Is it possible?

I tried `mutate(var1:var3 = ...)` (this syntax works in `select()`) but it doesn't work. It would be very convenient to be able to write this in one call, so I can just insert it in the chain of operations rather than having to go outside of them and do it as above. In my case, I have more than 3 columns that need to be transformed so writing them all out is not an option. An alternative using `gather()` and then `spread()` from `tidyr` is possible but not very elegant and time consuming.

Comment: The answer by @lukeA is the way to go. I would just note that even if you used the "normal" `mutate`, you wouldn't need to call it several times like you did in your question but once like so: `d %>% mutate(var1 = var1 * m, var2 = var2 * m, var3 = var3 * m)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
d %>% mutate_each(funs(. * m), var1:var3)
```

Comment: `mutate_each` is now deprecated in favour of `mutate_all` and `mutate_at`